# sql query for 3 tables

Tags: sql, database

i have 3 tables (A,B,C)
Table A -

```
ID Name
1  Sam
2  Manuel
3  Jane
```

Table B

```
ID Tab_A_ID Name
1   1       Meer
2   1       Kutti
3   2       Mikaro
```

Table C

```
ID Tab_B_ID Price
1  1        255.11
2  1        30.52
3  3        125.22
```

I need a query that shall pick up the top price for TableA-Name from TableC. So only 1 top price for 1 nae record.
e.g.-

Sam - 255.11

Manuel - 125.22

How can i get this?

Comment: revised problem -
i have 3 tables (A,B,C)
Table A -

    ID Name
    1  Sam
    2  Manuel
    3  Jane

Table B

    ID Tab_A_ID Name   Place
    1   1       Meer   Hina
    2   1       Kutti  Hineya
    3   2       Mikaro Seene

Table C

    ID Tab_B_ID Price
    1  1        255.11
    2  1        30.52
    3  3        125.22

I need a query that shall pick up the top price for TableA-Name from TableC based on tableB-place. So top 1 price for Sam in Hina is 255.11
e.g.-

Sam - 255.11 in Hina

Manuel - 125.22 in Seene

How can i get this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the max price per entry in A:

```
SELECT     a.Name,
           MAX(c.price)
FROM       a
INNER JOIN b
ON         a.id = b.tab_a_id
INNER JOIN c
ON         b.id = c.tab_b_id
GROUP BY   a.id, a.name
```

To get the max price per entry A per entry B:

```
SELECT     a.Name,
           b.Name
           MAX(c.price)
FROM       a
INNER JOIN b
ON         a.id = b.tab_a_id
INNER JOIN c
ON         b.id = c.tab_b_id
GROUP BY   a.id, b.id, a.name, b.name
```

Note that entries in A without corresponding entires in B or entries in B without corresponding entries in C will *not* appear in the result.  Use LEFT JOIN if you want to include these in the result.